# Displaying .gif in Android?

Tags: android, image, android-activity, gif

I want to know how to "easily" display a gif image (animated) ...in android.

Is there a custom library or something like that, maybe a .jar I can download and use it to link a .gif resource and display it an an activity ?

I know this has been asked a lot of times on SO, but there's not one easy solution, and a beginner like me could get lost easily.

I'm looking for something like what Picasso does in displaying images from URLs... 
Google search didn't find me anything, only empty questions with half hearted not working/ deprecated answers.

As a last resort, here I am.

So, is there an easy way to display .gifs in an android ?
(Possibly, as easy as displaying text or an image ?)

Comment: Use a frame\sprite animation. It's a best way.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below tutorial which explains how to use gif image in android:
http://droid-blog.net/2011/10/14/tutorial-how-to-use-animated-gifs-in-android-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

you can use this library it does support **GIF**

https://github.com/koush/ion